# How do I assign one value to multiple factor levels at once in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns, last name and a new column where I want to assign "Yes" or "No".

```
df <- data.frame(x <- as.factor(c("a","b","c","d","e")), y <- NA)
colnames(df)<-c("last name", "newCol")
```

Let's say I want to assign "No" in `newCol` for "a", "c", "e". How do I assign "No" to all three factor levels at once?

I tried using the logical operator, |, with the factor levels, but it did not work. I have been able to do it by assigning "No" to individual levels, but I find it inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to check for `"a"`, `"c"`, `"e"` in one step:

```
df$newCol[df$`last name` %in% c("a", "c", "e")] <- "No"
df;
#last name newCol
#1         a     No
#2         b   <NA>
#3         c     No
#4         d   <NA>
#5         e     No
```

Or using a `tidyverse` approach using `ifelse`:

```
require(tidyverse);
df %>% mutate(newCol = ifelse(`last name` %in% c("a", "c", "e"), "No", "NA"))
#  last name newCol
#1         a     No
#2         b     NA
#3         c     No
#4         d     NA
#5         e     No
```

or slightly different using `replace`:

```
df %>% mutate(newCol = replace(newCol, `last name` %in% c("a", "c", "e"), "No"))
```

Comment: No problem @ybcha204, glad it helped. Please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.